# is there a way asp.net to trigger whether to display a fieldset?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, visual-studio-2010, gridview

I am creating a program with asp.net c#, i am using multiple gridviews to show different criteria of data on 1 page, each of these criteria has a title,

Now, if one of the gridviews happens to have no data it will not show, however the title of the gridview will still be there as it is purely html fieldset and legend.

Are there any functions i could use to trigger the visibility of the title from the c# code?

Thanks
(screenshot below)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `runat="server"` to fieldset and set `Visible = true` or `false` as usual (of course you need to set an ID, too).

Answer (score 2):

You can surround each grid in an <asp:Panel... with a visibility on the panel set to a server based property (e.g. `Visibility=<%# RecordsReturnedGreaterThanZero %>`
so that the panel will only render the contents if there are some records returned in your query. Simply provide a property in your codebehind that acts as the boolean operator